# Friend function that takes 2 classes in parameters - 'Class' not defined

Tags: c++, friend-function

I encountered some issues while working on friend functions. I want to use a friend function that uses two different classes in parameters. Here is the sample of code:

ObjectA.h:

```
#ifndef OBJECTA_H_
#define OBJECTA_H_

#include "ObjectB.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ObjectA {
private:
    friend void friendFunction(ObjectA &,ObjectB &);

public:
    ObjectA();
    virtual ~ObjectA();
};

#endif /* OBJECTA_H_ */
```

ObjectB.h:

```
#ifndef OBJECTB_H_
#define OBJECTB_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ObjectA.h"

class ObjectB {
private:
    friend void friendFunction(ObjectA &, ObjectB &);

public:
    ObjectB();
    virtual ~ObjectB();
};

#endif /* OBJECTB_H_ */
```

Both .cpp files for ObjectA and ObjectB are empty (empty constructor and destructor). Here is the main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ObjectA.h"
#include "ObjectB.h"

void friendFunction(ObjectA &objA, ObjectB &objB){
    cout << "HIIIIIIIIIII";
}

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    return 0;
}
```

This all thing sends me the following error :

```
'ObjectA' has not been declared
```

And this error is pointing to this line in the ObjectB.h :

```
friend void friendFunction(ObjectA &, ObjectB &);
```

As you can see, the ObjectA.h file has been included in the ObjectB.h file. So I don't know where my error come from.

Maybe I'm using friend function in a wrong way ?

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ObjectA.h, replace:

```
#include "ObjectB.h"
```

with:

```
class ObjectB;
```

Make the corresponding change in ObjectB.h.

What's happening is that main.cpp is including ObjectA.h. Before declaring the `ObjectA` class, ObjectA.h includes ObjectB.h. When ObjectB.h tries to include ObjectA.h *again*, the `#ifndef OBJECTA_H_` test fails, meaning the `ObjectA` class isn't declared when the friend function is declared, leading to the error.

You can break this loop in your specific case by using a forward class declaration instead of `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

Baybe using template function instead? But this way you will break encapsulation.

```
class A{
private:
  template<typename T, typename B>
  friend void friendFunc( const T&, const B&);
  int m_a;
};

template<typename A, typename B>
void friendFunc( const A& a, const B& b){
  std::cout << a.m_a << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    friendFunc<A, int>(A(), int(3));
    return 0;
}
```